# synchronized(...) on a code block with var=Thread.currentThread()

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I'm reading a code with this class:

```
public class MultiThreadedServer implements Runnable {
    // some more code
    protected Thread runningThread = null;

    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
        }
        // lots of code
    }
}
```

What is this supposed to mean ? The thread itself is used as flag to lock the ressource ? I don't get it at all.

Anyone knows ?

Comment: `// blablahbla` - `// lots of blahblahblah` - this is a no-go to me. `this` points to the instance of `MultiThreadedServer `, not the Thread (which has an invalid identifier)

Comment: I love the space in  `protected Thread running thread = null;`

Comment: It doesn't use the thread as lock, it uses the Runnable object. Is the same object given to multiple threads? Are there other methods in the Runnable which synchronize?

Comment: Ah, typo, sorry guys. @Steven Pessall nothing else is synchronized in this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is a `Runnable`, not a thread, so the synchronization is *not* done on the thread itself as you write.

It might be somewhat confusing, but very workable if eg. the object is accessed by several concurrent threads.

Cheers,

Comment: So it synchronize the Runnable to avoid concurrent access to the run() method shared among threads ?

Comment: @Csi not the entire `run` method but only the `synchronized(this)` block

Answer (score 1):

`this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();` Simply gives you a link to the current thread.

This way you don't have to call `Thread.currentThread()` all the time, saving you the method call overhead.

And uhm, the space in  `protected Thread running thread = null;` doesn't help either...

Comment: The field `runningThread ` isn't just for convenience, I high doubt it is used  only in the `run` method, especially since it is marked as `protected`.

Comment: Ah, typo on the runningThread, sorry.